# How do I grep text in remoting mode

Tags: powershell, remoting

In powershell (2.0) the following works nice and fine:
cmd /c echo "hello" | select-string hello

Outputs "hello".

When running this in remoting mode, text is not printed:

```
Invoke-Command -ComputerName myserver -Credential user.name@domain.tld { cmd /c echo "hello" | select-string hello }
```

Why, and how do I grep text of commands (exefiles) in remoting mode?
(windows7 on client, 2008r2 on server. Commands can run fine, ports are open, etc)

Answer (score 2):

Don't you want to do:

```
Invoke-Command -ComputerName localhost { cmd /c echo "hello"} | select-string "hello"
```

Comment: No, the actual script block which is executed on the remote server is much larger than this example, and from one single of the commands which are executed I want to minimize it's console output.

Answer (score 1):

The output of `Select-String` is not a string, but a `MatchInfo`, which can't be returned over the `Invoke-Command` connection.

Simply pipe the results of `Select-String` to `Out-String`, and you will get your output~:

```
Invoke-Command -ComputerName myserver -Credential user.name@domain.tld 
    { cmd /c echo "hello" | select-string hello | out-string }
```